# How emojis work on iphone and android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

On Web I Understand say, slack, uses their own parser and replaces `:name:` with span tag and background image. But in mobile it seems to be built in.

However, I dont get how it works out between different versions of Android and between IOS and Android.

Is there a universal icons text?

So `:S, :|, ...' if so where can find it.

Comment: Unicode. Do a google search on Unicode.

Comment: I know what unicode is, but is it used by keyboards of mobile?

Comment: I think mobile devices use unicode by default. Some third party apps may use their own mapping to convert unicode to `:xxx:` so the emoji looks the same across all the platforms.

Comment: Here's the mapping I used in my app: http://emoji.codes/family

Comment: Android and iOS use Unicode which includes many standard Emoji characters. These make no use of anything like :S or :| or whatever. They are actual characters just like the letters A or B. This is why I can send an email from one computer/phone to another and see the same text including any of the standard Emoji characters defined by Unicode.